# Subquery returned more than 1 value with IN statement

Tags: sql-server-2005

This is my query.

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY str_league_name ) AS RowNumber    
from vw_leagues 
where p_league_id in 
( 
select f_league_id from udf_get_trg_get_distinct_leagues_mem_in(5,'5,60327,532,4388,4424,4404,60131,66315,36704,38258,38409,38768,38907,39092,40566,42194,42512,42738,42773,43427,48418,58169')
)
```

this query

```
select f_league_id from udf_get_trg_get_distinct_leagues_mem_in(5,'5,60327,532,4388,4424,4404,60131,66315,36704,38258,38409,38768,38907,39092,40566,42194,42512,42738,42773,43427,48418,58169')
```

returns a dataset of

f_league_id
20
21
24
25
31

But I get this error:

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I am not using any of the above operands. I am using an IN statement. Why am I getting this error?

Here is the udf:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION udf_get_trg_get_distinct_leagues_mem_in (@myint int,@ids varchar(max))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
SELECT distinct a.p_league_id as f_league_id
from tb_leagues a
inner join tb_league_groups b on (a.p_league_id = b.f_league_id)
inner join tb_group_members c on (b.f_group_id = c.f_group_id)
where 
    (
    a.f_member_id_creator = @myint
    or a.f_member_id_officer1 = @myint
    or a.f_member_id_officer2 = @myint
    or a.f_member_id_officer3 = @myint
    or a.f_member_id_officer4 = @myint
    or a.f_member_id_officer5 = @myint
    )
or c.f_member_id in (select number from dbo.iter$simple_intlist_to_tbl(@ids))
)
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
```

And here is the function within that function

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[iter$simple_intlist_to_tbl] (@list nvarchar(MAX))
   RETURNS @tbl TABLE (number int NOT NULL) AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @pos        int,
           @nextpos    int,
           @valuelen   int

   SELECT @pos = 0, @nextpos = 1

   WHILE @nextpos > 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @nextpos = charindex(',', @list, @pos + 1)
      SELECT @valuelen = CASE WHEN @nextpos > 0
                              THEN @nextpos
                              ELSE len(@list) + 1
                         END - @pos - 1
      INSERT @tbl (number)
         VALUES (convert(int, substring(@list, @pos + 1, @valuelen)))
      SELECT @pos = @nextpos
   END
   RETURN
END
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
```

Comment: Please post the definition of 'udf_get_trg_get_distinct_leagues_mem_in'. It would help to see the return trype of this UDF.

Comment: I have updated this posting with your request. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in the udf_get_trg_get_distinct_leagues_mem_in, since when using the IN operator is expected to have multiple values returned.

You should test the values for duplicates as well.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. The issue was in vw_leagues, not the function. I didnt have a top 1 in the statement in sub selects in that query.